# Lubuntu 19.10 won't boot because of "iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS"

Tags: boot, lubuntu, bios, lxqt

I'm on an Acer Nitro 5 (intel i5), trying to dual boot Windows 10 with Lubuntu 19.10

Everytime i try to boot into the installer (or into the os after installing from the safe option on the boot menu) it would get stuck on "iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS", i think i got it to actually boot once after waiting on this message for a little while. But it was definitely not useable since I'm not about to wait over 5 minutes just to start lubuntu.

Lubuntu 18.04 installs and runs normally but 19.10 doesn't work. But i want to use the LXQt desktop on the newer lubuntu versions and I couldn't replicate the same lxqt setup and look on the lubuntu 18.04.

Has anyone experienced the same issue or know a possible way to resolve the issue?

Heres the (visible) terminal output:

[photo of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMMDt.jpg)

Also a somewhat relevant question:

I can't find download links for lubuntu 18.10 or 19.04 even though there are release articles on the lubuntu website with (dead, not found) links to the download files. Does this version exist and why can't i find it? Does anyone still have a copy of the .iso files?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  I'm unaware of any references to 18.10/19.04 downloads on the lubuntu site (https://lubuntu.me/downloads/) so I'd appreciate it if you could provide a link so I can correct it, though I suspect you weren't at an official Ubuntu/Lubuntu site, if unsure where to go I'd recommend asking ubuntu.com (ie. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) and not search engines as it's under Ubuntu/Canonical control and not algorithms (like search engines that can't tell real from fake)

Comment: As for your issue, did you verify your ISO after download?  (if you look up the Lubuntu manual there is some details there, ie. https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/1.1/retrieving_the_image.html).  Second did you use the validation of install media before trying to try/install?  (ie. "*Check disk for defects*" option mentioned in the manual - https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/1.3/installation.html)  It would be my suggest first step.

Comment: FYI:  Code blocks (the "{}") should be used for pasted text from a terminal.

Comment: @guiverc yeah sorry for that i didnt know that

Comment: @guiverc https://lubuntu.net/lubuntu-19-04-disco-dingo-released/ https://lubuntu.net/lubuntu-18-10-cosmic-cuttlefish-released/ these showed up on a google search so i thought those are the official website

Comment: i was confused because there is lubuntu.me and lubuntu.net

Comment: i didnt do checks or verification of the iso files but i was able to install it on a vm.

Comment: Ok, I will try installing with a different flashdrive and actually running the checks, but i really doubt its because of problems with the installation media, because I have done this multiple times with the same flash drive and other os.

Comment: In my experience it's the write to media that fails the most often, not the thumb-drive itself. Lubuntu's discourse site maybe helpful too (https://discourse.lubuntu.me/).  If it's not media (I've watched for that being 'cleared') I'd check another flavor of 19.10 as I'd expect other flavors to react the same (ie. it's a kernel or base issue, not Lubuntu specific; and this site is great for that), but I'll only think about that post validation.

Comment: what is the https://discourse.lubuntu.me/ website for? also the problem is probably not lubuntu specific (i have seen other people on different linux distros having similar a issue) so, i doubt ubuntu 19.10 will install, but i havent tried it yet.

Comment: If you go to the Lubuntu official site (https://lubuntu.me/), the discourse site is the *Forum* link if selected. It's a good place to speak with Lubuntu devs.  You've now hinted it's possibly kernel/stack specific, so you'll gain little over here in that case (unless a *dev* happens to own a like device).  ps:  I'd still edit your question and use {} tags to format your pasted detail from CLI; easier to read posts get more responses.

Comment: ok i will try to ask there, i also replaced the text with the actual photo because the google lens output has a lot of mistakes

Comment: sorry I had a bad typo in my last comment; it should have been "so you'll gain little over **there** in that case"... ie. if kernel/ubuntu-base related, this is a good site.   The Lubuntu forum is good for Lubuntu specific detail (esp. LXQt), this site has a greater audience for the Ubuntu base...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105880/discussion-between-m-isa-and-guiverc).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)